# postgres command line script not working on windows 2012 R2 Server but does work on Linux/Mac

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

The following PSQL command works on Mac/Linux:

```
psql "dbname='public' user='myuser' password='XXXXXX' host='some.host.com' port='5432'" --file=permissions.sql
```

But when I try to use the same command on windows, it will login but not execute permissions.sql.  I tried changing permissions.sql to \dbbackup\permissions.sql so that I would specify the the full path to the sql script.  That didn't appear to help.

When I run the command in Linux, psql logs into the db and executes the script.  The same command logs me in to the db but doesn't execute.  I just get a command prompt like this:  DATABASENAME=>

Then I have to execute \q to logout.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting the arguments separately and not as one string? Or move the `--file` to the beginning? Though psql should work the same on all platforms. Never seen that way of defining arguments though.

Comment: Moving the --file command to the beginning worked.  Thanks so much for the quick reply!